# Android, how to get list of external storage directories

Tags: android, storage

I'm developing an application that download a lot of data ( about 5 GB) from the network. Due to internal storage disk space, I want to allow the user to choose the "sd card" destination: internal sd card or external sd card (micro sd).
Consider that the path can change for each manufacturer, how I can retrieve a list of all "sd cards" available? (even if is an internal application that will be used only with Samsung tablet)

Comment: `all "sd cards" available? ` ??? have you ever seen a device that can handle more than one card?

Comment: `an internal application` ?? What is an internal application? And what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in several ways.

First:  'the old way' use `getExternalFilesDirs()`. The first entry is external memory. (The same delivered by `getExternalFilesDir()`). The second entry the sd card. The third a USB OTG drive.

Second: Use `Storage Access Framework` and let the user use with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Third: For Android 7 only. `Use Volume Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Internal Memory:

```
String extStore = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
File f_exts = new File(extStore);
```

External SD Card:

```
String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY`_STORAGE");
File f_secs = new File(secStore);
```

Comment: `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");`. Will deliver `null` on most devices nowadays. Your code is not prepared for that.